# Match between characters with regex.h

Tags: c, regex, posix

I'm trying to match strings like this: `"labels": [{"name": "labelname"`
where labelname can contain any amount of letters, numbers or whitespaces. I tried `"labels": \[\{"name": "(.*?)"` ,which works in regex101.com but i dont get any matches using the posix regex.h. If i do `"labels": \[\{"name": "` it matches the string up to the fist `"`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse JSON with regex. (I can't say for sure because you haven't provided enough information.) Don't do that. Use a JSON parser and save your sanity.

Comment: I worry about the `\[\{` notation, because in C source code, you'd need `\\[\\{` to encode the backslashes as backslashes.  But you've not shown your code so it really isn't very easy to know what you're up to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a class that select everything apart from the closing character, like that :

```
"labels": \[\{"name": "([^"]*)"
```